# Создать класс для работы с обыкновенными дробями

Tags: c++, ооп

Всем привет,есть у меня такая задачка.

> Создать класс для выполнения арифметических действий с обычными
> дробями. Предусмотреть методы класса для:
>
> - вычитание двух дробей. Результат хранить в сокращенной форме.
> - умножение двух дробей. Результат хранить в сокращенной форме.
> - Печать чисел в форме a/b, где а – числитель, b – знаменатель.

Многое я уже написал,но не понимаю что значит хранить результат в сокращенной форме,может кто-то подсказать?Буду очень благодарен

Comment: если в результате вычисления получилось 2/6, то нужно сокращать до 1/3.

Comment: вероятно имеется ввиду, что дроби должны быть сокращены

Comment: Аа,все настолько просто.Спасибо большое